# Analog Keyboard on Moto360 to replace voice commands?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, wear-os

I'm (trying) to use [Analog Keyboard for Android Wear](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/analogkeyboard/index.htm) from Microsoft Research.

The wearable (Moto360) is properly setup for Bluetooth debugging and the install procedure for the Keyboard finishes as expected:

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
4df11bb241805f93        device
localhost:4444  device

$ adb -e install com.microsoft.research.analogkeyboard-Signed.apk
50 KB/s (5322694 bytes in 103.401s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.microsoft.research.analogkeyboard-Signed.apk
Success

$ adb -e shell ime enable com.microsoft.research.analogkeyboard/.KeyboardService
Input method com.microsoft.research.analogkeyboard/.KeyboardService: now enabled

$ adb -e shell ime set com.microsoft.research.analogkeyboard/.KeyboardService
Input method com.microsoft.research.analogkeyboard/.KeyboardService selected
```

After that, the Analog Keyboard app is visible in the list of installed apps on the watch and, when opened, works really fine.

*The challenge* is to make it replace voice commands. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to intercept or change the voice input mechanisms used throughout Android Wear.

Comment: I work at Google alongside the Android Wear team. Most voice inputs on Wear directly listen to the microphone, rather than rely on something you can plug into with an alternate system.

Comment: Btw. my idea was to replace voice with already set and selected IME (in my example com.microsoft.research.analogkeyboard/.KeyboardService), so when I choose Reply SMS (in Messanger app), my prefered IME is chosen.